# Why we need confidence intervals for performance estimation?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, confidence-interval, bootstrap, auc

I am asked to calculate the AUC-ROC for a classifier on a test set. Then I must take bootstrap samples of this test set and calculate their AUC-ROC. Lets say that I will perform $n$ bootstrap samples. Therefore I will compute $n$ AUC-ROC.

What I can't get is the interpretation of the confidence interval.

I am thinking that is related to the variability inherent in the performance estimation since we deal with finite samples (test sets). The original dataset is of finite size say $N$, therefore if I examine another test set of size $N$ then I will get a different AUC-ROC.

So the estimated performance can vary depending on the test set but what the confidence interval tell us about this variation?

**Update**

I would like to add some details with regards to the original question.

First, assume we have collected a test set of size $N$ and we wave estimate the performance on this test set, say $p_1$. Then in order to construct a confidence interval, we resample from the population new test sets (or boostrap sampling from the original sample), again of size $N$.

So we end up with the sample $S = \{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$ (AUC-ROC) values and the CI is:

$$ (\bar{p}-1.96\frac{s_p}{\sqrt{n}}, \bar{p}+1.96\frac{s_p}{\sqrt{n}} )$$

where $\bar{p}$ is the mean and $s_p$ the standard deviation of the sample.

From a frequentist perspective, this interval by no means bears probabilistic interpretation. The pοpulation parameter $P$ is either in the interval or not. So interpretations like:

1. A range of plausible values for the population parameter.
2. Contains with $95\%$ probability the population parameter.

are nonsense (see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Common_misunderstandings)). What is correct, is that if we repeated this process ad infinitum, that is collecting samples $S_i$ and calculating their confidence intervals $\text{CI}_i$, then $95\%$ of them will contain $P$.

Based on that, it is not clear to me what purpose the CI serves. The sources that I have read say that it gives us an idea of the variability of the statistic (AUC-ROC herein) under consideration (see the second slide in this [notes](https://research.tuni.fi/uploads/2022/10/5c020961-creating-confidence-intervals-for-ml.pdf)).

Here is my current (possibly wrong) understanding of the CI: assuming that the size $N$ is fixed, then as $n \to \infty$ the variation we observe in $S$ reflects the variation in the sampling distribution of $P$ (and this resemblance becomes better with increasing $n$).

Could someone explain the necessity of confidence intervals when reporting performance metrics (or other test statistics) and what additional information they provide us? In other words, why just the estimated performance in the test set is not enough?

Comment: What does a confidence interval tell you in a simpler setting, such as a confidence interval for a mean?

Comment: It tells me that if I take $N$ such intervals, then $95\%$ of them will contain the true population mean. With regards to the question, if I take $N$ such intervals, then $95\%$ of them will contain the true AUC-ROC. Why is it usefull though? Either the true parameter will be in a confidence interval or not.

Comment: It sounds like you doubt the utility of a confidence interval in general, not just for assessing a machine learning model. Do you just prefer the interpretation from a Bayesian credible interval? In order to answer your question in a way that would be expected to help, it will be important to know what you do not like about confidence intervals.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the comment, I have updated the question.

Comment: It sounds like your question is really about how to interpret a confidence interval. Details related to machine learning performance seem tangential to this.